# How to add ComboBoxItem using C# code when clicking on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a comboBox that changes messages according to the language.

But I didn't find a way to make it work.

What I try to do is whenever I change the language to ComboBox change the language of the message

Code XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="TestC" Initialized="MyComb"/>
```

Code C#

```
var SelectLang = "";
switch (LangSelect.SelectedIndex)
{
   case 0:
       SelectLang = "en-US";
       break;
   case 1:
       SelectLang = "es-ES";
       break;
   default:
       break;
}

for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    string month = new CultureInfo(SelectLang).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i).ToString();
    TestC.Items.Add(month);
}
```

Currently I am using Initialized but I can only create the ComboBox when starting the wpf application, this makes the language not applicable, in order to work I have to save the language and open it again.

How can I get ComboBoxItem to be created by clicking on the ComboBox box?

Comment: You want to wire up the SelectionChanged event.  When it happens, clear the Items list and repopulate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `SelectionChanged` event to refresh the combobox of the months of each culture date.

use this code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LangSelect" Width="200" Height="30" SelectionChanged="LangSelect_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Please Select Culture" Selector.IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="en-US"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="es-ES"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Name="TestC" Width="200" Height="30"/>
```

and

```
private void LangSelect_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (TestC != null && LangSelect.SelectedIndex > 0)
   {
       TestC.Items.Clear();
       ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)LangSelect.SelectedItem;
       for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
       {
          string month = new CultureInfo(item.Content.ToString()).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i).ToString();
          TestC.Items.Add(month);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       if (TestC != null)
          TestC.Items.Clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about using it in the language selection comboBox, thanks for that